# LightsOut board randomizer not solveable

Tags: java

I'm trying to recreate Lights Out, and a board randomizer to start off the game. When I use my boardRandomizer, I still find the board to be impossible to solve, even though my code starts the board from an all off position, then randomly toggles lights an x amount of times, using Math.Random to randomly pick lights.

```
final int intBoardSize = 5;
boolean[][] boolLightState = new boolean[intBoardSize][intBoardSize];

public void boardRandomize() {


    for (int row = 0; row < intBoardSize; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < intBoardSize; column++)
            boolLightState[row][column] = false;

    int randomRow, randomColumn;

    for (int randomCount = 0; randomCount <= 50; randomCount++) {
        randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
        randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
        toggleLight(randomRow, randomColumn);
    }

}

public void mouseToggleLight (int x, int y) {

    for (int row = 0; row < intBoardSize; row++)
        for (int column = 0; column < intBoardSize; column++)
            if ((Math.sqrt (Math.pow ((y - intLightPosition [1][row][column] - intLightRadius), 2) + Math.pow((x - intLightPosition [0][row][column] - intLightRadius), 2))) < intLightRadius)
                toggleAdjacentLights(row, column);

}

public void toggleAdjacentLights(int row, int column) {

    toggleLight(row, column);

    if (row + 1 >= 0 && row + 1 < intBoardSize)
        toggleLight(row + 1, column);

    if (row - 1 >= 0 && row - 1 < intBoardSize)
        toggleLight(row - 1, column);

    if (column + 1 >= 0 && column + 1 < intBoardSize)
        toggleLight(row, column + 1);

    if (column - 1 >= 0 && column - 1 < intBoardSize)
        toggleLight(row, column - 1);

}

public void toggleLight(int row, int column) {

    if (boolLightState[row][column] == false) 
        boolLightState[row][column] = true;
    else
        boolLightState[row][column] = false;

    repaint();

}
```

Comment: How do you determine that the board is impossible to solve? I suggest logging all steps the randomizer does and then do them backwards.

Comment: Because there is a set solution that has been calculated and figured out by many. By moving all the lights to the bottom row of the board, there are only about 5 different combination possibilities that should show up, and I keep getting ones that are not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int randomCount = 0; randomCount <= 50; randomCount++) {
    randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
    randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
    toggleLight(randomRow, randomColumn);
}
```

should be

```
for (int randomCount = 0; randomCount <= 50; randomCount++) {
    randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
    randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * intBoardSize);
    toggleAdjacentLights(randomRow, randomColumn);
}
```

Otherwise the randomizer performs illegal moves.

You should refactor your code so that `toggleLight` is a private method in `Board`to prevent such errors in the future.

Consider the following:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Board {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board board = new Board();
        boardRandomize(board);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board.boolLightState));
    }

    public static void boardRandomize(Board board) {
        board.resetBoard();

        int randomRow, randomColumn;

        for (int randomCount = 0; randomCount <= 50; randomCount++) {
            randomRow = (int) (Math.random() * board.intBoardSize);
            randomColumn = (int) (Math.random() * board.intBoardSize);
            board.toggleAdjacentLights(randomRow, randomColumn);
        }
    }

    private final int intBoardSize = 5;
    private boolean[][] boolLightState = new boolean[intBoardSize][intBoardSize];

    public void resetBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < intBoardSize; row++)
            for (int column = 0; column < intBoardSize; column++)
                boolLightState[row][column] = false;
    }

    public void toggleAdjacentLights(int row, int column) {

        toggleLight(row, column);

        if (row + 1 >= 0 && row + 1 < intBoardSize)
            toggleLight(row + 1, column);

        if (row - 1 >= 0 && row - 1 < intBoardSize)
            toggleLight(row - 1, column);

        if (column + 1 >= 0 && column + 1 < intBoardSize)
            toggleLight(row, column + 1);

        if (column - 1 >= 0 && column - 1 < intBoardSize)
            toggleLight(row, column - 1);

    }

    //make private to prevent access
    private void toggleLight(int row, int column) {
        if (boolLightState[row][column] == false)
            boolLightState[row][column] = true;
        else
            boolLightState[row][column] = false;
        // all of the above can be simplified to
        // boolLightState[row][column] = !boolLightState[row][column];
        repaint();
    }
}
```